# Iterating through two lists with different lengths

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I'm trying to draw a calendar type thing in TikZ, and need to place the days of the week around a circle. I can't see how I can repeat the 7 day pattern over a range of 365 positions.

This works:

```
\foreach \i/\j in {1/Sat,2/Sun,3/Mon,4/Tue}{
    \node at (0,\i) {\j};
}
```

but I'm looking for something like `{1/Sat,2/Sun,3/Mon,...,365/Sat}` - surely I don't have to manually write out 365 pairs?

So basically I'm looking to iterate over two lists at once, except one is shorter than the other, and I'd like the short one to repeat until the end of the long one.

Comment: You should create a spearate external list with the days of the week and use a simple mod7 calculation to grab the day into your `foreach` loop.

Comment: @SebGlav I thought of that but wasn't sure how to get the items in a list by index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}

\newcommand\week{{"Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun"}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \row using {div(\i-1,7)}, 
                evaluate=\i as \col using {mod(\i-1,7)}] in {1,...,365}
    \node[draw, circle, inner sep=1pt, minimum size=9mm] at (\col,-\row) {\pgfmathparse{\week[\col]}\pgfmathresult};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]